# Unity crashes in Unity Editor but runs fine as built application

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, match, game-development

When I run the game, it loads fine. But as soon as I start to swap pieces Unity crashes and the project closes immediately.

This happens after clicking on one piece, then dragging it to another place and then at the moment I let go of my mouse click the unity project crashes and closes completely.

UPDATE:

- I was able to find out that it builds normal and runs fine as built
  application (e.g. on iPhone).  But running the game in the Unity
  Editor leads to an instant crash. Anyone know why? There is no error
  message in the console.
- After compiling the scripts I get following message in the console:

  ```
   There are inconsistent line endings in the 'Assets/Scripts/Board.cs' script. Some are Mac OS X (UNIX) and some are Windows. This might lead to incorrect line numbers in stacktraces and compiler errors. Many text editors can fix this using Convert Line Endings menu commands.
  ```
- Not sure if this is of importance, but every time i reopen the project from Unity Hub it opens the project along with the `Package Manager Window` and the `Build Settings Window`.

If there is anymore information that I can post up, let me know what and where to find it (sorry I am fairly new to Unity)

Comment: Post the text of the exception and its call stack, else we can't help you.

Comment: where do i find the call stack?

Comment: To view a detailed callstack on the exception in the console you do the following: `Edit` -> `Project Settings` -> `Player` (then scroll down to Stack Trace) -> `Stack Trace` and check `Full` on `Error` and `Exception`. Then when you'll get an error or exception in the Editor, you can click on it in the Console and view the callstack in the details bar below it. Just Remember to set them back to ScriptOnly before building a final production version.

Comment: Also note that *not crashing* when playing on the iPhone doesn't not mean it runs fine 100%. It means you don't see a crash. But it can have several errors underneath that could be handled locally or not be fatal to the application. But if there is no error, it could mean there are issues with accessing assets (especially external ones, such as files).

Comment: Posting some code and text of the exception will help finding the correct answer.

Comment: @TheNomad I did what you said with the Stack Trace. I don't get any Error/Exception messages in the Editor though because Unity crashes instantly without me seeing anything in the Console first. And when I then reopen the project there is nothing on the Console either.

Comment: Wait, you meant the executable crashes. I thought only the project does. OK, I see. Open Run (Win+R) and go here: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Unity`. There you should have an `Editor` folder. Rename it to something like `Editor_old` or something similar. Next, start the Unity Editor, reproduce the crash and upload the `Editor.log` file from ``%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor` somewhere like pastebin and post the link here.

Comment: I can' t find any Editor folder, nor an directory like '/Local/Unity' in the 'Builds' folder (which i guess you mean by '/AppData' ?) The 'Builds' folder I am talking about is in my unity project folder.